# Color coding individual rows in a DataGrid based on row contents

Tags: c#, sql, datagrid

I have inherited a .NET 2.0 c# project that does the following:

- Executes a SQL Query
- Binds the SQL result to a DataGrid

I have found a fair bit of information on how to achieve this in a DataGridView, however this does not seem applicable to a DataGrid (missing methods/Event handlers that DataGridViews have).

What I am trying to achieve, is based on the results of a column set the background color of the column to red (for example).

Does anyone have any suggestions, is is converting to a DataGridView going to be the only realistic option (I would like to avoid this if possible!)

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple `DataTriggers` in your DataGrid Style.

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="1" AutoGenerateColumns="True" VerticalAlignment="Top"  ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <DataGrid.RowStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ItemIndex}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background"  Value="Red"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ItemIndex}" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Background"  Value="Blue"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.RowStyle>
     ...
   ...
</DataGrid>
```

More info on `DataTriggers` here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatrigger.aspx